# Proof for IG Primes

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

As an enthusiast in Mathematics, yet aware of this site policy, I am sure enough that this question has the fate to remain closed in the future, yet I have made my mind emotionally that before it occurs, someone will be able to answer or even comment on this work.

In 2022, I published a book named [A Young Mathematician](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BD2TRSZQ) where I first presented my idea of Imtiaz Germain primes, a version of Sophie Germain primes. I had invented this series, in notation explained later in my book [Research of the Century](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BKMVDVLY) as following:

> The following defines the set IG (named Imtiaz Germain primes), are defined above. We will enhance this, and give meaning  to Imtiaz Germain primes further with a clear scope.
>
> $$
> p \in Y
> $$
> $$
> \dagger p = p
> $$
> $$
> \to 2(p)+1 = \mathbb{P}
> $$
> $$
> \to 2(p)+1 = \mathbb{C}
> $$
> $$
> \to 2(p)+1 = \mathbb{P}
> $$
> $$
> \to p \in IG
> $$

Here, $p$ is Sophie Germain prime and the $Y$ is defined as following according to Research of the Century:

> $Y: Y \in \mathbb{N} \wedge \frac{\mathbb{N}}{2} = \phi$

In basic terms, if you take a Safe prime, and apply $2p+1$ on it, you need to get a Composite number, and if you apply $2p+1$ on this Composite number, you get a prime number, it is a Imtiaz-Germain prime.

The sequence continues as:

> 3, 23, 29, 53, 113, 233, 293, 419, 593, 653, 659, 683, 1013, 1103, 1223, 1439, 1559, 1583, 1973, 2039, 2273, 2339, 2549, 2753, 3299, 3359, 3593, 3803, 3863, 4019, 4409, 4733, 4793, 4919, 4943, 5003, 5279, 5639, 6173, 6263, 6269, 6323, 6563, 6983, 7433, 7643, 7823, 8243, 8273, 8513, 10253, 10529, 10799, 10883, 11393, 11579, 12329, 12923, 13049, 13619, 13649, 14159, 14879, 16673, 16823, 17579, 17669, 17939, 18443, 18803, 19373, 19913, 20249, 20393, 20693, 20753, 20789, 20879...

The book A Young Mathematicians checked upto Ten Million numbers, to see if the ending numbers are on 3 and 9. See the copy of the book A Young Mathematician [here](https://aitzazimtiaz.github.io/A-Young-Mathematician/) which computed it to what I claimed. How can I write a proof that such numbers end on 3 and 9 always? All I want is how to start my proof formulation, I do not require a full proof.

P.S. I am extremely sorry for hurting everyone time, but I have a passion to share this work, downvote and close vote is certain enough. I just would appreciate your comment on this idea in general and would love to see a proof. Considering the fact I am barely 16, I plea guilty for posting question I should not have done, but would love to know you read my idea.

Edit 1: 3 is a Sophie Germain prime, it has safe prime 7, apply $2p+1$ on it you get 15 (it needs to be composite), apply $2p+1$ on it again, you get 31 (a prime) so 3 is IG prime. 5 is a Sophie Germain prime, with 11 as Safe prime. Apply $2p+1$ on it, you get 23, which is prime so it needed to be composite so 5 is not IG prime.

Comment: Sorry once again, and i know already this question is going to be closed :,) but as I have OCD, and am tempted to know what people think of this, please respect my enthusiasm and I know there exist a lot of faults in this question as it will be closed soon for clarity :')

Comment: The definition isn't clear at all.  Are you saying, "we consider primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is composite but $2\times (2p+1)+1$ is again prime"?  But of course, $3$ doesn't satisfy that.  I suggest:  edit your post to show clearly what test $3$ passes and, say, $5$ fails.  Don't refer to some text we don't have access to.

Comment: Thanks @lulu 3 is not a prime but a Sophie Germain prime, apply $2p+1$ on it, it gets safe prime 7, I say apply $2p+1$ on it you get 15, a composite number, apply $2p+1$ on it once more you get 31 which is prime, so 3 is a IG Prime

Comment: Let me try editing, I really am confused though, let me see it

Comment: $3$ is a prime, though.  So, you start with a Sophie Germain prime...you consider the associated safe prime, and then you iterate $n\mapsto 2n+1$ twice on that safe prime and, if you get a prime that time, you call the original prime an IG prime?

Comment: prime and a Sophie Germain prime both, but here it is a Sophie Germain prime being more reserved

Comment: This all seems terribly complicated.  Let $f(n)=2n+1$.  I think you mean to consider primes $p$ such that $f(p)$ and $f^3(p)$ are both primes.  Is that right?

Comment: @lulu correct, a little bit wrong, apply 2p+1 on the Safe prime, get a composite number at all cost, apply 2p+1 on it again and you get a prime, so that Sophie Germain prime is an IG prime

Comment: I edited a typo.  You want $f(p)$ and $f^3(p)$ to be prime, right?  Oh, and you require $f^2(p)$ to be composite?  So $5$ fails.  Is that it?

Comment: $f(p)$ is a safe prime, firstly?

Comment: Well, if it's a prime, then of course it is safe.  That's the definition of safe (as you are starting with a prime).

Comment: yes @lulu you got it! And I am saying that then $p$ always end on 3 and 9! You got this entire idea.

Comment: May I give you some friendly advice?  If you want to be taken seriously, don't use titles such as "Research of the Century".

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks so much! I cannot change its name now :( but yea I never said this book solves N vs NP or Navier Stokes, from the description right away this book is just some random ideas of a 16 years old kid. By the way, it is an honor for me talking to you :)

Comment: To follow up on what Robert said, if you name something after yourself, people will wonder why. Further, joining your name to one of the more famous mathematicians in history in the process does look very unusual. No mathematician does this that I've seen. I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are claiming this: if $p$ is prime such that $2p+1$ is prime, $2(2p+1)+1=4p+3$ is composite and $2(4p+3)+1=8p+7$ is prime again, then $p$ must end with $3$ or $9$ in its decimal representation.

After checking trivial cases $p=2$ and $p=5$, we conclude that $p$ must be odd and $p\pmod 5$ can only be $1, 2, 3$ or $4$. Now:

- If $p\equiv 1\pmod 5$ then $8p+7\equiv 8\cdot 1+7=15\equiv 0\pmod 5$ so it cannot be prime, being divisible by $5$.
- If $p\equiv 2\pmod 5$, then $2p+1\equiv 2\cdot 2+1=5\equiv 0\pmod 5$ and again cannot be prime, being divisible by $5$.

The only two possibilities left are:

- $p\equiv 3\pmod 5$, i.e. $p$ ends with digit $3$ or $8$, so as $p$ is odd it ends with $3$
- $p\equiv 4\pmod 5$, i.e. $p$ ends with the digit $4$ or $9$, so as $p$ is odd it ends with $9$.

Comment: +1 @StinkingBishop thanks so much, one more thing to ask finally, do you find my idea quantitative and nice to be an original research? :)

Comment: Depends on what else you have discovered about "IG primes". Those things should be (1) nontrivial and (2) ideally useful enough so that people asking "why study IG primes and not SB ('Stinking Bishop') primes" would have a satisfactory answer.  I don't think the property "ends with $3$ or $9$" is particularly hard to prove. But let that not stop you, it is a bit of a gamble but you might stumble on something bigger and/or more interesting, I don't want to discourage you.

Comment: that really helps! tysm

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz Number theory statements are really divided into two categories. One concerns properties of numbers _unrelated to their representation_ and the other is concerned with properties of numbers _in a particular (say, decimal, binary etc.) representation_. Note that us humans using base $10$ is a biological, not a mathematical artifact. (Humans _happen_ to have $10$ fingers.) That fact usually (not always!) makes the statement less interesting. Still, you may want to think of some statements about IG numbers in the *first* category. Maybe generalise this result to any base somehow?

Comment: This is actually a nice idea I must consider at all costs! I am still a kid in this big mania stuff, but I do think these numbers are a good fit for cryptography and random algorithm. Further, I am thinking of converting these numbers to hexa decimal number system. I really pay tribute to you for showing this concern :)

Comment: I wish you best of luck :)

Comment: Negative votes have begun, the question is about to sink, I just want to thank you for being an awesome angle for me! I wanted both motivation and help for the proof, you certainly gave me a big treasure!

Answer (score 0):

The definition as given in the text is a bit hard to parse, but the concept is clear enough:

For each $n\in \mathbb N$ define $F(n)=2n+1$.  Of course we can iterate this, getting $F^2(n), F^3(n)$ and so on. It helps to note that $F^2(n)=4n+3$ and $F^3(n)=8n+7$.

A prime $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime if $F(p)$ is also prime.  The OP is tightening this condition by only considering Sophie Germain primes such that $F^2(p)$ is composite but $F^3(p)$ is prime.  These are to be called $IG$ primes.

Thus, an $IG$ prime is a prime $p$ such that both $2p+1$ and $8p+7$ are prime, but $4p+3$ is composite.

Thus, the iterates of $3$ under $F$ are $\{3,7,15,31\}$ so $3$ is an $IG$ prime.  $5$ is not because it's iterates are $\{5,11,23,47\}$ and $23$ is prime, counter to specifications.

To see that any $IG$ prime must end in $3$ or $9$, consider the other options.  Outside of easily checked small examples, primes can only end in $\{1,3,7,9\}$ so we just have to eliminate $1$ and $7$.

To eliminate $1$:  note that, if $p$ ends in $1$, then $F^3(p)$ is divisible by $5$, hence can not be prime.

To eliminate $7$:  note that, if $p$ ends in $7$, then $F(p)$ is divisible by $5$, so $p$ can't even be a Sophie Germain prime.

And we are done.

Comment: +1 Thanks so much!